# python regular expression date format

Tags: python, regex

my regexp is
reg = "April \d{1,2}"

I want things like "April 20"

but not "April 2000"

How do I fix it?

Thanks,

Cheng

---

sorry, need to modify my question, the reg im using is

"((january|febuary|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|\

jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)\

\D{0,3}\

((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9])))"

want to take April 20
not April 2000

Comment: Using the regex you posted you should not get April 2000 anyway, as you allow only 2 digits.

Comment: Yes, Joanna. I'm asking how to write a regexp so it will only take the format I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `April \d\d?\b`.

Answer (score 0):

roughly that's what you want probably:

```
\w+\s*[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]\b
```

It wouls still allow things like Feb 30 though, you'll need to tweak it depending on how accurate you need it to be

Answer (score 0):

Python regex matching tries to match the begin of te string, so the final `00` is simply not used by the regex matching. To force a match until the end of the string use the `$` end of string marker.

Like `April \d{1,2}$`